# USB camera not recognised

Tags: usb, camera, usb-on-the-go, usb-peripherals

I wish to use a USB camera with a Samsung Tab S2 t813. I have the USB Camera Pro app installed, however when I plug in a camera, the app does not register the device. On two other Samsung phones with the same app running, there is no problem, the video is shown.

Is it likely to be a hardware fault, or is there some configuration that needs to be adjusted or a certain driver necessary?

The tablet is running Android 7.0 and kernel 3.10.84-14953299 dpi@SWDH7017 #1.

Thanks

Comment: On Android/Linux drivers are integral part of the kernel. If the USB webcam driver is missing on one device you can't install the driver, instead you would have to rebuild a matching kernel and enable the usb drivers(s) and then replace the kernel (which is the first step to a custom ROM).

Comment: I've compiled Linux kernels before but have no clue about android. Can you please suggest places where i can find information? Is it unusual for Samsung to omit webcam drivers in their kernels? The two phones that I've tested have both been Samsung - one is a Galaxy J8

Comment: Doe USB OTG works at all on the device where the webcam is not recognized? You can test it by connecting a simple USB mouse or keyboard. And there are also OTG checker apps in Play Store.

Comment: Thanks. USB OTG Checker reports that it the tablet has "Android Compatible USB OTG" . Under "List of connected devices" however, it reports no device found" when I attach a mouse or camera

Comment: I tested the mouse with Word. I works on my J8 phone, but not on the tablet unfortunately

Comment: The app "USB Diagnostics" fails to recognise the USB camera on the tablet but recognises it on the J8. The mouse is not recognised on either

Comment: Keyboard also doesn't work. I think my tablet is faulty. I will return it.